# JSONException : value <html> of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to make a login interface in android , i want to connect to a php file that connects to a database.
the database is called "daymanager" and the table is "login"

And this is the php file called login.php :

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dbname="daymanager";

$con= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$BD= mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
//$username=$_POST['username'];
//$password=$_POST['password'];

$query=mysql_query("select username,password from login");
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($num==1)
{
while($list=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$output=$row[username];
echo json_encode($output);

}
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

and this is the java code in eclipse :

```
package com.mounzer.test;





import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Activating extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button login;
    EditText user,pass;
    String username,password;

    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub







        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activ);



        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        login =(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        user=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost =new HttpPost("http://192.168.48.1:6789/aglprojet/Login.php");


        username=user.getText().toString();
        password=pass.getText().toString();



        try

        {
            namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
            {
                entity=response.getEntity();

                if(entity !=null)
                {
                    InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
                    JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                    String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                    String retPass = jsonResponse.getString("password");



                    if(username.equals(retUser) && password.equals(retPass))
                    {
                    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit=sp.edit();
                    spedit.putString("user",username);
                    spedit.putString("pass",password);
                        spedit.commit();


                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Succesfully connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                }


            }


        }catch(Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



    }
     private void Log(String string, String retUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            /*
             * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
             * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
             * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
             * and returned as String.
             */
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(null, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(null, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

}
```

when I try the application from my mobile , it gives me this exception :

**org.json.JSONException** : value `<html>` of type **java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject**

can anyone tell me what should I do please
thank you

Comment: The result from `convertStreamToString(instream);` must be a valid JSON string. What is the value of `entity.getContent()`? Attempting to create a [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) from an (invalid JSON) String will produce the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that something is running into an error and returning an error message wrapped in HTML. Try calling your authentication script via a browser or anything that lets you see what it actually returns.

Also, you don't seem to return any fields in your output, so `getString("username")` etc is never going to work. If you want to return multiple things from your authentication script, put them into an array or something and `json_encode` that.

And finally, are you sure it's a good idea to send the password to your client...? (I'm guessing you're trying to do this judging by the fact that you try to read them back from the response)